# Fourier series of $\psi (x) = \cos(2x)$ using the basis $e_n = \dfrac{e^{inx}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$

Tags: operator-theory, fourier-series

I have to calculate the Fourier series of $\cos(2x)$ using the basis $e_n = \dfrac{e^{inx}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ of $L_2 (0,2\pi)$. If I calculate the coefficients of the series I get
$$c_n = \langle e_n|\psi\rangle = \int_{0}^{2\pi}dx\dfrac{e^{-inx}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\dfrac{e^{i2x}+e^{-i2x}}{2} = \int_{0}^{2\pi}dx\dfrac{e^{ix(-n+2)}}{2\sqrt{2\pi}} + \int_{0}^{2\pi}dx\dfrac{e^{ix(-n-2)}}{2\sqrt{2\pi}} = \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}\left[-\dfrac{i}{2-n}[1^{-n+2}-1]+\dfrac{i}{n+2}[1^{-n-2}-1]\right] = 0$$

Am I right? Or I'm doing something wrong? Thanks for the help.

Comment: You have to handle the case $n=2$ and $n=-2$ seperately (you effectively have a $0/0$ expression in those cases).

Comment: What happens for the case $n=2$? Notice that $e^{ix \, (n-2)}|_{n=2} = 1$. Other cases may apply.

Comment: $\int_0^{2\pi} e^{nix}(\frac {e^{2ix} + e^{-2ix}}{2}) dx = 0$ unless $n = \pm 2$